# How to Redirect to new Page when timer finished time in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on Online Examination System in ASP.NET. I want to use timer in my project. When time is finished it should be redirect to new page and auto save result. Please help me.

Comment: It's better  to use JavaScript.

Comment: do it in javascript. once the server finishes sending the page it cannot talk to the client

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian Nonsense, it very much can. How do you think StackOverflow updates your notifications or informs you of new questions? Websockets. Here's a .NET project that utilizes them: http://signalr.net/

Comment: yes, given the nature of the program you would want to enforce this sever side somehow. perhaps you should send the exam data every time it changes for saving and reply back with a failed validation when the timer has expired on the server?

Comment: @GravCube When a page is finished on the server and delivered to the client, the server cannot initiate to it again that is a HTTP1 issue, in HTTP2 it is solved by giving the server the ability to initiate. What you do with signalR is to have the client continuously ask the server for new information done with javascript (client).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code behind by this:

```
 this.Head1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='time in second ;url=your Url'>"));
```

or by `setTimeOut` function in JavaScript` like this:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "Your location";
}, 10000);//After ten seconds it will be redirect to your location
```